# Magento2 import table rates from Magento1

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, backend

Is there a way to export tables rates from a magento1 shop and import them to a magento2 shop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. M 1 go to shipping methods=> table rates, change scope view to "Main Website" (maybe you have different name)
   You will see now export button if not change view to correct one.
2. Go to M2 and set same settings.
   Open your scope view to see export and import button.
3. Compare file I thing they are same with same settings.
4. import file to M2. I think you can also find this file in m1 import directory in case when export is only exporting template.